# Facebook send dialog appears and disappear

Tags: javascript, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am developing a facebook application, i am trying to send a private message to my app user, but the popup appears and disappear very next time, i used this script from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/, when i click 2 to 3 times on link(specified below) then a popup appears, remember i am includind all.js and a div having id= "fb-root" by facebook

```
FB.init({
    appId: '<?=$this->facebook->getAppID()?>', 
    xfbml: true, 
    cookie: true
});
function send_message(user_id) {
    FB.ui({
        to: user_id,
        method: 'send',
        name: 'name',
        link: 'http://www.something.com'
    });
}
```

link is,

```
<a href="" onclick="send_message('<?=user_id?>')">send msg</a>
```

Any help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="" onclick="send_message('<?=user_id?>')">send msg</a>
```

An empty `href` attribute is interpreted as pointing to the same URL you are currently on.

And since you are *not* suppressing the default action of that link, I assume your browser just reloads the page when that link is clicked – and since that, you are seeing the dialog for a short while, until your browser has reloaded and rendered the page again.

Make that

```
<a href="#" onclick="send_message('<?=user_id?>');return false;">send msg</a>
```

instead, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Did your console printed anything else? Check the Facebook object in the Console. May be there is something missing. Are you sure the appId is set corretly and the user_id as well. Facebook can be pretty bitchy about that.

Comment: All the things are pretty fine, i mentioned that when i put two to three consecutive clicks, then a window appears, and message also sent to the user as well, but worried with that problem appearing and disappearing